# do something if element hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i check a if an element is visible or hidden with jquery and perform some action?

below given is my form related code,

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Full name: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
DOB: <input type="text" name="dob">
Address: <input type="text" name="address">
</form>
```

i need to hide the full name text field when first name text field or last name text field is displaying.

Comment: i am sorry i haven't seen this answer before.

Comment: :hidden, or :visible selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/visibility-filter-selectors/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try something like this

```
if($('#testElement').is(':visible')){
   //what you want to do when is visible
}
```

for your code

```
if($('input[name="firstname"], input[name="lastname"]').is(':visible')){
  $('input[name="fullname"]').hide();
}
```

REFERENCE

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: lasttname? It seems you copy pasted the typo :-)

Comment: @Vishal solved it ...

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('input[name="firstname"], input[name="lastname"]').is(':visible') === true)
    $('input[name="fullname"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
<input type="text" name="fullname"> 
to 
<input type="hidden" name="fullname">
```

to make an input field hidden

Answer (score 0):

this should work `$(element).is(":visible")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the logic behind your question, but this demo should do the trick. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hYQJY/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#firstname').is(':visible') || $('#lastname').is(':visible'))
    $('#fullname').parent().hide();

})
```

I added some parent divs to hide the text and the input on once. If you want you can wrap the text in label tag for more clearly output.